# Some theories and laws of Operations Research?

Tags: optimization

Can I know some theories and laws of Operation Research which has being widely used nowadays?

Comment: Hi @deepan. I feel this question is overly broad, and does not have a correct answer. As a field with a history of over 100 years, people have discovered lots of theories and laws.

Comment: I agree, and am voting to close. If you can be more specific about what you are looking for, the question can be salvaged.

Comment: If it is closed, I will voie to reopen. So the question is broad, so there is not a single unique correct answer. Is that the crime of the century?

Comment: As it stands, your question sounds like you are saying, "tell me about the _whole field_ of OR." If you mean something like, "what are the fundamental theorems that are widely applicable," that might be a bit tighter.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone It is not the crime of the century. It is simply so broad that it's hard to understand what is being asked. Feel free to vote as you find appropriate.

Comment: @deepan To clarify: you are looking for OR theories that are *widely used* but *not widely known*?

Comment: I think the original version of the question made more sense. The current version, "widely used nowadays though it is not known widely" seems like it is so narrow that it may be the empty set, depending on the interpretation of the two instances of "widely".

Comment: Just the fact that the answers are no longer relevant to the edited question is IMO an indication that the question was broad. i.e. none of the answers posted, answer the *edited* question of "widely used nowadays but not widely known"

Comment: The question has now been edited back to its original. Yes, it's broad. Good O.R. practitioners are usually broad. So I don't think there's anything wrong with broad questions. If each answer were required to mention all (well-known) theories of O.R., that would be too broad. But the question only requests "some" of the theories, and I believe it is fine for individual answers to list one or more, but not necessarily all, such theories. From that perspective, I don't think the question is too broad to be usefully answered/.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE, deepan, and thanks for contributing your first question here. However, in its current state, the scope of the question is too broad - there are very many theories/laws that are widely used; hence the reason it is currently closed. To improve your question, you may wish to focus specifically on particular areas of OR (e.g. linear programming), and ask for some theories there. Alternatively, you may wish to add more specific constraints to your question (e.g. theories that are important to OR but *not* widely known)? I will vote to reopen once some improvements have been made.

Comment: OP reposted [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1171/491).

Answer (score 6):

[Little's Law:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law)  $L = \lambda W$. Widely applicable. Widely used.

Answer (score 6):

How about [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_duality) and [strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_duality) duality?